# Am I allowed to use a passport from another country if using my US passport would require a visa?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, us-citizens, dual-nationality

I am traveling to Tunisia, a country in North Africa, where I am a citizen. I am also a US citizen and was born here. I normally use my US passport going to Tunisia, and of course I have no problems. However, this year I want to travel with some of my Tunisian family from Tunisia to Turkey as tourists. However, US citizens need a visa but Tunisians don't. Would it be a problem if I used the Tunisian passport I when entering Turkey or would this cause problems when I come back to the US and go through customs? Would I have to tell US customs that I went to Turkey or no since I would be using my Tunisian passport?

Answer (score 5):

It shouldn't be a problem. Use your Tunisian and American passport when checking in and clear passport control in Turkey with your Tunisian passport. On your exit in Turkey, check in with your American passport, pass border control in Turkey with your Tunisian passport and enter the US on your USA passport.

Comment: Why would he have any questions when he returns? This is even recognized by DoS: https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/legal-considerations/us-citizenship-laws-policies/citizenship-and-dual-nationality/dual-nationality.html *"Most U.S. nationals, including dual nationals, must use a U.S. passport to enter and leave the United States. Dual nationals may also be required by the foreign country to use its passport to enter and leave that country. Use of the foreign passport does not endanger U.S. nationality. "*

Comment: Just normal questions, where have you been and so forth. As a US citizen, he can't be refused entry. I'll edit to remove the "some questions".

Comment: Got it. I thought you said he'd be questioned more because he used two passports.

Comment: It might cause some questions, but not because of two passports.  Rather, a visit to Turkey arouses suspicion as people going to ISIS usually go through Turkey.

Comment: @LorenPechtel `Rather, a visit to Turkey arouses suspicion as people going to ISIS usually go through Turkey` True, although now ISIS sympathizers and fighters are heading away from the area.

Answer (score 3):

Of course it's allowed. Dual nationality is permitted under US law and the US thus has no say in what passport you use elsewhere.

If checking the stamps, the US official might ask if you hold another passport, in which case you simply say yes and show the Tunisian passport if asked (sometimes happens, but is no cause for concern)

Answer (score 3):

Neither of the current answers has addressed your last question, so I will do so.

> Would it be a problem if I used the Tunisian passport I when entering Turkey

As covered elsewhere, no.

> would this cause problems when I come back to the US and go through customs?

It will not cause problems.

> Would I have to tell US customs that I went to Turkey

Yes, you will have to tell them that.  The customs declaration form requires you to list all of the countries you've visited on your trip.  Omitting Turkey from your declaration could get you in trouble, but listing Turkey won't have any adverse consequence.

> or no since I would be using my Tunisian passport?

It doesn't matter what passport you used; if you have been in Turkey, you have to tell them that.  The reason they ask is because they're interested in the goods you might be carrying; that has nothing to do with which passport you will have used to enter Turkey.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, I hold multiple citizenship and I do this all the time in order to avoid paying for a visa in certain countries.

Comment: This 'answer' is not clear, it looks like you are the OP adding information. Maybe you can add more information and beef out the answer. As it stands it is very likely to be deleted.